# Macro for debugging info with function name and line number in C plus plus

Tags: c++

How to have a macro kind of thing in C++ for having a function name and line number in the debugging info. For example

```
std::cout << "F:" << __FUNCTION__ << ":L:" << __LINE__ << ":"
          << "Doing specific operation" << std::endl;
```

In the above statement, I would like to have some shorter notation for

```
"F:" << __FUNCTION__ << ":L:" << __LINE__ << ":"
```

in order to replace the same with an alias. I should be able to use the alias through out the function for logging purposes.

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work or not worked? Please review [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And or course please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Why just no define another macro? `#define DEBUG_INFO "F:" << __FUNCTION__ << ":L:" << __LINE__ << ":"` ? Note that `__FUNCTION__ ` and `__LINE__ ` will be expanded in place, after the containing macros are expanded, so they will still contain the correct information, despite being defined inside some header file

Comment: You might look at [std::experimental::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location).